# jquery css add IE8 filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am try to make the css3 hack for background-cover in IE8 by using the jquery code

```
        activeBg.css({ "filter": "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='" + backgroundImage + "',sizingMethod='scale'), progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=30);"})
```

But it does not work? why?

Comment: hey - can you explain, what this property exactly does in Internet Explorer ? (the output)

Comment: @happy2deepak The css property? Or jquery? 
I run the code but not set the Filter css property.
If i ran it like an array the left: 0 and filter it set the style left: 0; in the dom but still not set the filter

Css: 
This filter is an fix for the css3 command Background-size: cover; 
and set the opacity on the images on 30%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i got it self.

A some resone CSS don´t want to inline style filter.
So i did this and it works greate

```
    // IE8 HACK
    // Find the background image and regex the uneedet
    var backgroundImage = activeBg.css('backgroundImage').replace(/url\(|\)/gi,"");
    var scale = '"scale"';
    // If this and ie8? if true append an inline stylesheet
    if($("html").hasClass("lt-ie9")) {
        var ie8CoverImg = ".module.car-types-headline .background.active { filter: 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src="+backgroundImage+", sizingMethod=" + scale + ") progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=30)'; -ms-filter: 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src=" +backgroundImage+ ", sizingMethod="+scale+") progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=30)'; }";
        $("head style#ie8-cover-fix").remove();
        $("head").append("<style id='ie8-cover-fix'>"+ ie8CoverImg +"</style>");
    }
```